# I want my app to run things in the background, even when the user is donig other things on his Android

Tags: java, android

What should I look at to get started?

Is it Timer? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a Service:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html